# documentation for error object for azure service

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cosmosdb

I want to know what does the error object looks like in the callback function for some azure functions such as `blobService.createBlockBlobFromText`, `blobService.createContainerIfNotExists`, `documentClient.queryDocuments`, `documentClient.replaceDocument`.

I am able to find their function documentation easily such as https://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/BlobService.html#createContainerIfNotExists , but it does not explain what the error object look like.

Could you point me its documentation?

Comment: See if this helps: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/lib/common/errors/errors.js.

Comment: I am not sure how the Error looks like. Does it contains an status code field? It will be great if there is a documentation.

Comment: So,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, SDK source code is based on REST API. If you want to know the error status code,you could refer to the REST API Status Code documents:

Azure Storage Service:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/status-and-error-codes2

Azure Cosmos DB:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/http-status-codes-for-cosmosdb

If you want to know the error body,you could catch the http request by [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) Tool.